# Where can the definition for GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, x) be found?

Tags: jslink, client-side-rendering

I've been working with JSLink lately and have come across the GenerateIIDForListItem() method on several occasions. I see why it's being used but does anyone know where I can find documentation for it?

Here's an example of it in action:

```
function changeRowColor(ctx){
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    var rowId;

    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
        rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        tr = document.getElementById(rowId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#d24b19";
    }
}
```

I realize that there have been other questions asked about CSR documentation but I was hoping to learn if anyone has found anything specific to the GenerateIIDForListItem() method.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any official documentation for that.

If you are on-prem, your best bet may be to crack open clienttemplates.debug.js and search in there.

If you are on SPOL you might be SOL.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I was hoping that wasn't the case. I hate to say, "it just works", but it looks like I'm going to have to do that since I don't have access to anything else.